# How can I confirm that an element is the first of its class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to know whether the element being clicked on is the first of its kind, because if it is, I need to uncheck a checkbox and re-run a function that prevents inputs being matched; however, something that I thought would be seemingly simple is apparently not that simple. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
$(".remove-box").unbind().click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this) == $(".remove-box :first")) {
        //uncheck tickbox and remove matching details class
    }

    removeDelegate($(this));
});
```

Has anyone got any suggestions for how I can make this work?

Comment: Have you tried: `$(".remove-box:first")`  (no space before :first)

Comment: I think @freedomn-m is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "first of its kind" I assume you mean its type, i.e. tag. In which case:

```
if ($(this).is(':first-of-type)) {
```

If you mean first of a certain class, it gets more involvd. First of a certain class in the entire document? In the current container? Assuming the latter:

```
if ($(this).prevAll('.className').length) {
```

Comment: Worth noting that `:first-of-type` only works against siblings.   https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/  *"Selects all elements that are the first among siblings of the same element name"*

Comment: Yes. It makes no logical sense to apply a hierarchical selector to anything other than a flat nodelist.

Comment: You'd be surprised... actually, I'd completly disagree with that statement as it depends on the structure of the doc and what is being looked for (but not the place for more details, enough that we see it differently and worth adding the caveat) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `$(".remove-box").first();`. `$(".remove-box")` will get you all of the elements with that class, `.first()` will get you the first of those selected elements.

Edit: By the way, for current major desktop browsers, use your selector followed by `.first()` rather than `:first` in your selector. Using the function is much quicker, [here](https://jsperf.com/selecting-the-first) is a site that you can run tests on to check performance of certain selectors.

Comment: I tried that, but it still evaluates as false. I logged both to the console with: `console.log($(this)); console.log($(".remove-box").first());` and they are literally the same, except the `$(this)` reference does not have `prevObject` when logged. Is this what is causing the evaluation to fail? If so, how can I change my condition?

Comment: @A.Appleby any chance you can update [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t694oqjm/) with some of your html so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Marked answer below

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".remove-box").unbind().click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $firstRemBox=$(this).parent().find(".remove-box").first();
    if($(this) == $firstRemBox) {
        //uncheck tickbox and remove matching details class
    }
    removeDelegate($(this));
});
```

But I think that's better:

```
$(".remove-box").off().one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $firstRemBox=$(this).parent().find(".remove-box").first();
    if($(this) == $firstRemBox) {
        //uncheck tickbox and remove matching details class
    }
});
```

Comment: This still evaluates as false as well

Comment: but your .remove-box is a checkbox?

Comment: It's a button - the checkbox I need to untick is unrelated in this context